# What does it means?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-usage

A: "Books don't grow on trees."

B: "Oh, well, technically, yes, they do."

B:" They're made of paper. "

A: "Sarcasm, Owen
is that really the weapon you're reaching for?"

A: As deputy library monitor, I have banned you from my library.

B: How tragic that you're forced to threaten me with this undeserved authority.

A: How tragic for the world of bibliography that you even exist.

C: Causing trouble AGAIN, Owen?

B: That... I...

D: I think we know who wears the long trousers there.

"i think we know who wear the long trousers there"
What does this mean? Any ideas? How to use it?

https://subsaga.com/bbc/childrens/4-o-clock-club/series-6/

Answer (score 1):

In England, in the past, schoolboys would wear short trousers until a certain age, then would be allowed to wear long trousers.  So "long trousers" would be a sign that one was "grown up".  Thus, "who wears the long trousers" means "which of them is more mature".

> **in long trousers**
>   (as postmodifying phrase) in a more mature, developed, sophisticated, etc., form.

[Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/long_trousers)

[image: trowsers]